# How do I generate the Google Maps API AuthenticationService token value

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to create a test script which needs to emulate some calls to the Google Maps API, the first call being the AuthenticationService (so that I subsequently make some further calls). The request which needs to be made is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fmyurlhere.net.au%2FOASIS%2FLocation.aspx&4sAIzaSyBzwCtz4eN5ZbnAsa_3qDFRoYP4vYSqB-c&5e1&callback=_xdc_._tl1sk9&token=10004
```

In the query string (at the end of the above URL) there is a token value that does not appear to be static and so the above doesn't work. In order to write my test script I need to work out how this value gets created and if there is any method call in the Maps API I can use to get this token.

This value must come from the Maps API somewhere. I've tried to look through the JavaScript but for some reason I'm unable to find this.

Is anyone familiar with the API that can point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Google API console you must have a gmail email, in this link you have entered information

https://developers.google.com/coordinate/authentication#client-id